# React-native: Shadow under TextInput not working properly

Tags: javascript, css, react-native

This is probably something trivial...I have a TextInput on top and a Listview directly under it. I want to have a slight shadow under the textinput at all times.

Problem is I only see the shadow when I pull down the list like so:
[image]

(there is no shadow when not pulling down the list)

here is the code:

```
   <View style = {{flex: 1}}>
       <View style={styles.searchBar}>
         <TextInput
          value={this.state.searchText}
          style={styles.searchBar}
          onFocus={this._searchTextFocus()}
          onChangeText ={(change) => {this._setSearchText(change)}}
          placeholder='Ask...' />
       </View>
          <ListView ....
```

Stylesheet:

```
  searchBar:{
backgroundColor: '#f5f5f5',
height: 40,
paddingLeft: 10,
shadowColor: "black",
shadowOpacity: 0.8,
shadowRadius: 2,
shadowOffset: {
  height: 1,
  width: 0,
},
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: ok I can just set a higher zIndex for the textinput view, but there surely is a better solution..